# In nodeja/nodered, how do i address this property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

[image: How do i address this JSON node programatically?]

I want to use this property in my function node. How do i address this property? msg.payload.tagData.???

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the square bracket notation:

```
msg.payload.tagData['0828CA741AEEB01700172093000004E3'].inIntensity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
msg.payload.tagdata['0828CA741AEEB01700172093000004E3']
```

if its dyanmic and you only need to access the first property, you can do

```
msg.payload.tagData[0]
```

if you want to dynamically get all of the data of those properties, you can loop through them

Comment: `msg.payload.tagData[0]` won't access that property.

Comment: are you getting null or undefined?

Comment: to access `inIntensity` you can do `msg.payload.tagData[0].inIntensity`

Comment: `tagData` is an Object, not an Array - so `tagData[0]` will not return the requested element.

Comment: you can still access objects using indexes

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the keys operator. This worked for me:

```
    payload=msg.payload;

for(let key in payload.tagData) {
    payload.tagData[key].epc = key;
    
}

return msg;
```

Comment: It really wasn't clear from your question that you did not know the values before hand.

Answer (score -1):

Those are hexadecimal attributes, you might need to convert them to decimal before you can access them

```js
const hexes = [
  '44c7b3b30db9c13b5',
  '68b739c1c6ca2bf7a',
  'f8fde53b68ee6b9eb',
  '7f61b32d42b4bed47',
  'f463cb64441e85a81',
]

let obj = {}

hexes.map((hex, i) => obj[`0x${hex.toUpperCase()}`] = i)

console.log(obj)
```